# Creating paypal checkout service for client

Tags: php, api, paypal

I want to create a paypal checkout enabled website for my client.
I tried searching for this but no luck ..

my actual plan is:
any visitor in the website asking for service service should be able to pay via paypal and the money should go to my client paypal account ..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) for this.  You can use the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter to pass in a 3rd party PayPal account ID or email address and the money will go directly to that account without the need to mess with Permissions.

If you happen to be working with PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It will make the Express Checkout Calls ([SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)) very quick and easy for you.